# Sort random array

Tags: data-structures

I'am given one array and in these i can have 10 elem. I have to manage these celem in sorting order

I tried using selection sort algorithm but the maximum swap constraint is not letting me do it.

Could any one lead me please.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any programming language in mind? Then please tag your question with it.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm is:

1. Starting from the right of the array, swap all a's to the left of the array.
2. Starting (again) from the right of the array, swap all b's to the left of the array after all the a's.
3. Starting (again) from the right of the array, swap all c's to the left of the array after all the a's and b's.

This all preserves your color swap limits, since for example a color 'e' can be moved exactly once in each of steps 1-5, but then is subsequently left alone.

To do this right, you have to be careful not to swap a color with the same color (also avoiding the degenerate case of this, of swapping something with itself).

The code is something like this (with some very rudimentary unit tests):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int limit_sort(char *input, size_t n) {
    int target = 0;
    int swaps = 0;
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (input[i] != c) continue;
            while (target < i && input[target] <= c) target++;
            if (target < i) {
                input[i] = input[target];
                input[target] = c;
                swaps++;
            }
        }
    }
    return swaps;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    struct {
        char *input;
        char *want;
        int want_swaps;
    } test_cases[] = {
        {"aaa", "aaa", 0},
        {"aba", "aab", 1},
        {"abc", "abc", 0},
        {"acb", "abc", 1},
        {"bbbaaa", "aaabbb", 3},
    };
    int fails = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(test_cases)/ sizeof(test_cases[0]); i++) {
        char t[32];
        strcpy(t, test_cases[i].input);
        int got_swaps = limit_sort(t, strlen(t));
        if (got_swaps != test_cases[i].want_swaps) {
            printf("limit_sort(%s) = %d, want %d\n", test_cases[i].input, got_swaps, test_cases[i].want_swaps);
            fails++;
        }
        if (strcmp(t, test_cases[i].want)) {
            printf("limit_sort(%s) -> %s, want %s\n", test_cases[i].input, t, test_cases[i].want);
            fails++;
        }
    }
    printf(fails ? "FAILED\n" : "OK\n");
    return fails == 0;
}
```

Comment: Here, "a" can be swapped only 1 time, "b" can be swapped 2 times and so on, the order of it is as given in the color array[26]={a,b,c,.....,z}.

Comment: The algorithm is the same, but you'll need to replace `char` with your `color` type, and use your `array` to determine the order. I hope this is already enough help.